Compose Screen OnDestroy Event Called Twice | NavHost
I need to detect the ON_DESTROY event for my Compose screen. I am using the code below to achieve this; It is called twice, but is there a way to detect it more robustly? The isObserverAdded helps me avoid adding multiple observers when navigating from the current screen to another screen. LaunchedEffect is called twice: when the screen is first composed and when I navigate to another screen, then back pressed to come back to the previous screen. LaunchedEffect is called again, so I wrapped the isObserverAdded. Is there a more robust way, like using DisposableEffect?
// Remember the observer to avoid creating multiple instances
val observer = remember {
    object : LifecycleEventObserver {
        override fun onStateChanged(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
                // Perform cleanup actions when screen is destroyed
                Log.d(TAG,"Screen is destroyed")
            }
        }
    }
}

// Remember a flag to check if the observer has been added
val isObserverAdded = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = lifecycleOwner.lifecycle) {

    if(!isObserverAdded.value){
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
    }
}


DisposableEffect(Unit) {         onDispose {             // Perform cleanup or any necessary actions here            //MyScreen is being destroyed         }     } why not use disposable effect?

When i navigate to another screen. OnDispose called. But i need to detect onDestroy screen only on current screen is destroyed like back pressed. If you know code, give me to avoid multiple observers added.

your current screen is your current composable right then onDipose will get called. BackPress can be detected using BackHandler

@SanthoshKumar There is no such thing as "Destroyed" in Jetpack Compose. There is only "entering the composition" and "exiting the composition". If something exits the composition, you can detect it via a DisposableEffect.

Yes i know, the problem is dispose is called when navigating to another screen from current screen. I need to detect when screen is completely disposed from navhost (stack).

You can never use Lifecycle to determine when a destination is popped off the back stack. Even the most basic cases of your activity being destroyed (e.g., due to a configuration change) will cause every entry to be moved to destroyed (despite none of them being popped off the back stack). In addition, when supporting multiple back stacks (to support bottom navigation), the Lifecycle of each NavBackStackEntry that is no longer on the current back stack is destroyed, but the state has not been destroyed - it'll get restored when you switch back to that back stack.
That's exactly why you need to use something that is tied to the state - namely, a ViewModel associated with the destination. Because ViewModels are treated alongside the other state of the NavBackStackEntry, it is kept across configuration changes (e.g., your Activity being destroyed) and is kept across changes between multiple back stacks.
That allows you to use the ViewModel lifecycle and its onCleared() method as the permanently destroyed API:

The lifecycle of a ViewModel is tied directly to its scope. A ViewModel remains in memory until the ViewModelStoreOwner to which it is scoped disappears. This may occur in the following contexts:

In the case of a Navigation entry, when it's removed from the back stack.

The ViewModel calls the onCleared method when the ViewModelStoreOwner destroys it in the course of its lifecycle. This allows you to clean up any work or dependencies that follows the ViewModel's lifecycle.

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
  override fun onCleared() {
    // Do your cleanup here
  }
}

@Composable
fun Screen() {
  // Now MyViewModel will get onCleared when this screen is popped
  val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
}

The reason you are getting multiple events is because remember is not rememberSaveable - that means that every time that screen leaves composition, your remembered value is not saved (that's the Saveable part), hence you are continuing to add a new observer every time you come back to that screen - you'll see 2, then 3, then 4, then more for every time you come back to that screen. As mentioned above, even if you were to use rememberSaveable, you still would not be handling the activity destroyed cases or the multiple back stack cases, both of which the above approach does handle.
As explained in this bug, Compose does not offer any Compose specific method for differentiating between temporary destruction (i.e., exiting composition because your screen went on the back stack) vs permanent destruction (i.e., getting popped off the back stack and your state being destroyed), hence why ViewModels are the only possible solution for this specific problem if you really do need a permanently destroyed signal.
